# Are there economical ways of synthesizing nanotubes?

Tags: nanotechnology, carbon-allotropes

I've heard Nanotubes will replace Li-ion batteries in the future and it is much more relevant. I just wanted to know could it really replace Li-ion batteries? Is synthesizing nanotubes economic?

Comment: I'd say a really important factor is if people want it or not. It was predicted that people will wear plastics in 21st century, while what really happened was, most ended up with comfy cotton clothing.

Comment: Sure, But people may need many things also such as quartz.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Funk98/mt5009-group-revolvecarbonnanotubefinal).

Comment: You would need equipment in order to handle something that is less than a nm. You could easily isolate graphene by taking scotch tape and sticking it onto graphite (tip of pencil) but of course you can't see it much less handle it with traditional tools

Comment: Depends what you call economic - nanotubes are expensive, but they are already used commercially.

Comment: If carbon nanotubes with additional 'bumps' (nanobuds) are counted, then the answer would be yes. See for example a Finnish company called [Canatu](http://www.canatu.com/nanobud/). They make touch sensors from the fullerene functionalised carbon nanotubes. If you are interested in the manufactory process, you might like to check this [Patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20090226704) of them, for example. Unfortunately I do not know about the possible uses of CNTs in batteries.